# Multiple people pressing submit is causing one person to lose score

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a small browser based game, the user plays the game and their score goes up. When they are finished with they game they type there name in and press submit. Via Ajax their username and score are sent to my leaderboard. They may then go to the leaderboard and view their score.

The problem I am having is, when two people press submit at the same time, whoever pressed it slightly before the other person loses their score.

Is there a fundamental reason that this is happening?

This is the Submit button code in game-test.html:

```
<form action="game-test.html"><button id="submitscore">Submit</button></form>
```

This is the Ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitscore").click(function(event){
var user = $('#username').val();
var value = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
$.post( "handler.php",
     { username: user, score: value });});});
```

Here is part of the handler.php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['score'])||isset($_REQUEST['username']))
{
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$value = $_REQUEST['score'];
var_dump($value);
var_dump($username);
}
```

more handler.php:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","censored","censored","censored");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Score)
VALUES
('$_POST[username]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[score]')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


mysqli_close($con);
```

Please ignore last name, it is not doing anything, I used a simple W3 guide for using the database because I am rather a novice.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition, but since you haven't shown any of the server-side code handling the updates, we can't help you.

Comment: Okay sorry that was my mistake. I just added the php code.

Comment: The code you've provided is not the code handling the updates.

Comment: Do you mean how the score is handled on the client side?

Comment: I'm going to assume that the score & username are written to a file (not a database). Then the file is later 'read' when looking at the leaderboard?... If so, One way of fixing this is to write to a new file $username, so that each user has their own file of highscores, then later combine the files together when viewing the leaderboard... I had an issue like this with user cookies....

Comment: The score and username are written to my database and that works. It appears as though, if he is clicking a game button while I press submit it trashes my score.

Comment: Would need to see more code then... The PHP code you're showing doesn't mean much besides that its requesting some parameters.

Comment: Okay the button that he is clicking when I try to submit my score is calling a javascript function which increments the score. But I assumed since that was happening on the client side it did not matter. If he is clicking the button which increments his score, I am not able to submit my score.

Comment: your php code isn't DOING anything with the clicks. it's just spitting out some information. you need to show HOW you're updating the scores on the server.

Comment: @user3369289 We still need to see how it's processed via server,...

Comment: Okay I edited the posted code. Is that what you need to see? The only thing I have not shown is the button code and the javascript file that changes the score as the user plays.

Comment: I think you need to change your handler.php file. Can you specify the file names above every code? Like which code is in which file? Because particularly, I think there is some problem in the script

Comment: Okay I just edited each code block.

Comment: Your code is all messed up, I doubt how its even working at ur end.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? My game is running fine. It just doesn't always let me post my score to the leader board. I think it is an issue with my friend playing at the same time I am uploading to the leaderboard.

Comment: Its actually quite late in my country right now, I'll answer ur question tomorrow. Oh And btw, try removing var_dump() And also put the More handler.php part inside the if(isset......) block. Use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in ur SQL. Try this much and tell.

Comment: Okay I made these changes and it is still giving me the same issue. It seems like when multiple users try to play the game it does not want to keep track of all of their scores.